# Is there a way to let external modules add implicits that can be used in an internal module?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

So I want to create a module that adds a trait Convertible and it's companion object that does something with a list of Convertibles on initialization.

```
trait Convertible {
    def toInt: Int
    def toBoolean: Boolean
    def toFloat: Float
}
object Convertible {
    val objects = List(1, 2, "", 4, 44.4f, "Hello World!", 42)
    
    def init(): Unit = {
        for(obj <- objects) {
            obj match {
                case con: Convertible => ImportantStuff.doStuff(con.toInt, con.toBoolean, con.toFloat)
                case _ =>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the question: Can I let other people's modules declare implicit declaration from certain types outside of this module?

Let's say 2 other coders that can't change the file "Convertible" but have access to it implement something like this:

```
object SomeGuysModule {
    implicit class ConvertibleString(val string: String) extends Convertible {
        def toInt = string.length
        def toBoolean = string.isEmpty
        def toFloat = string.length / 1024
    }
}

object AnotherGuysModule {
    implicit class ConvertibleInt(val int: Int) extends Convertible {
        def toInt = int
        def toBoolean = int != 0
        def toFloat = int + int / 10F
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to let the initial module recognize the additional modules' implicit conversions on the go?

Comment: You want a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) + the [**magnet pattern**](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scala-magnet-pattern/).

Comment: Your premise is faulty. `objects` is type `List[Any]`. None of its elements will pass the `Convertible` test.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **do not use any implicit conversions**. At least until you are completely sure that it's absolutely necessary. But in practice, it is not the case in 99.99% of tasks.

What you want to do have an idiomatic solution in scala - it is **typeclass pattern**. I advise you to read about it in [Scala with cats](https://www.scalawithcats.com/dist/scala-with-cats.html#anatomy-of-a-type-class).

So in your case, you could write

```
trait Convertible[A] {
  def toInt(a: A): Int
  def toBoolean(a: A): Boolean
  def toFloat(a: A): Float
}
```

or you can abstract from the second type as well

```
trait Convertible[A, B] {
  def convert(a: A): B
}
```

And then in client code in other modules with custom types, you can write typeclass instances for the desired classes.

```
object AnotherGuysModule {
  type AnotherModuleDataType = Int // there can be any type that you want
  objec AnotherModuleDataType {
    implicit val andtToIntInstance:     Convertable[AnotherModuleDataType, Int]     = ??? // implementation AnotherModuleDataType to Int
    implicit val andtToFloatInstance:   Convertable[AnotherModuleDataType, Float]   = ??? // implementation AnotherModuleDataType to Float
    implicit val andtToBooleanInstance: Convertable[AnotherModuleDataType, Boolean] = ??? // implementation AnotherModuleDataType to Int
  }
}
```

In the common code you can use it like:

```
def init(): Unit = 
  objects.foreach {
    case someInt: Int => 
      val toFloat: Float = implicitly[Convertable[Int, Float]].convert(someInt)

    case someBiInteger: BigInteger => 
      val toFloat: Float = implicitly[Convertable[BigInteger, Float]].convert(someBiInteger)

    case etc => ???
}}
```

It will be statically typed. You will have the power of parametric polymorphism You will be able to abstract over groups of types, program types relations.
For example, if you have a conversion from string to int, and int to boolean, you automatically have a conversion from string to boolean.
You just need to write this relation with one common function:

```
implicit def chain[A, B, C](a: A)(implicit aToB: Convertible[A,B], bToC: Convertible[B,C]): Convertible[A, C]  = {
  val b = aToB.convert(a)
  bToC.convert(b)
}
```

You can write a lot of utility functions that will eliminate boilerplate in client and library code. How to do it? Again, you can read about it in [Scala with cats](https://www.scalawithcats.com/dist/scala-with-cats.html#anatomy-of-a-type-class).

After that, it will look like

```
import your.lib.Convertable.syntax._
def init(): Unit = 
  objects.foreach {
    case someInt: Int => 
      val toFloat: Float = convert(someInt)

    case someBiInteger: BigInteger => 
      val toFloat: Float = convert(someBiInteger)

    case etc => ???
  }
```

PS: in Scala 3 there will be idiomatic syntactic sugar for type classes so it will be much cleaner and straightforward in usage.